# Use varargin for multiple arguments with default values in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab

Is there a way to supply arguments using varargin in MATLAB in the following manner?

**Function**

```
func myFunc(varargin)
  if a not given as argument
    a = 2;
  if b not given as argument
    b = 2;
  if c not given as argument
    c = a+b;
  d = 2*c;
end
```

I want to call the above function once with b = 3 and another time while the previous one is running in the same command window with a = 3 and c = 3 and letting b take the default value in the function this time. How can it be done using varargin?

Comment: Arguments go in order. If you give 2 arguments, then the function has arguments 1 and 2 defined. Options are to pass an empty array for unused args, check to see how many arguments are passed and do something different for 1 or 2 arguments, or using name-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to do this which have been available since 2007a (i.e. a long time!). For a much newer approach, see [Edric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634961/3978545).

1. Use `nargin` and ensure your inputs are always in order
2. Use name-value pairs and an input parser

---

**`nargin`**: slightly simpler but relies on consistent input order

```
function myFunc( a, b, c )
    if nargin < 1 || isempty(a)
        a = 2;
    end
    if nargin < 2 || isempty(b)
        b = 2;
    end
    if nargin < 3 || isempty(c)
        c = a + b;
    end
end
```

Using the `isempty` check you can optionally provide just later arguments, for example `myFunc( [], 4 )` would just set `b=4` and use the defaults otherwise.

---

**`inputParser`**: more flexible but can't directly handle the `c=a+b` default

```
function myFunc( varargin )
    p = inputParser;
    p.addOptional( 'a', 2 );
    p.addOptional( 'b', 2 );
    p.addOptional( 'c', NaN ); % Can't default to a+b, default to NaN
    p.parse( varargin{:} );

    a = p.Results.a;
    b = p.Results.b;
    c = p.Results.c;
    if isnan(c) % Handle the defaulted case
        c = a + b;
    end
end
```

This would get used like `myFunc( 'b', 4 );`. This approach is also agnostic to the input order because of the name-value pairs, so you can also do something like `myFunc( 'c', 3, 'a', 1 );`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the latest and greatest way to write the function (using [`arguments` blocks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-argument-validation-1.html#mw_1b62b6d6-a445-4c55-a9b9-9c70becfdbe6) from R2019b)

```
function out = someFcn(options)
arguments
    options.A = 3;
    options.B = 7;
    options.C = [];
end
if isempty(options.C)
    options.C = options.A + options.B;
end
out = options.A + options.B + options.C;
end
```

Note that this syntax does not allow you to say `options.C = options.A + options.B` directly in the `arguments` block.

In MATLAB < R2021a, you call this like so

```
someFcn('A', 3)
```

In MATLAB >= R2021a, you can use the new `name=value` syntax

```
someFcn(B = 7)
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know about this approach - my gut reaction is that the `=` syntax is pretty horrible; an assignment inside a function call seems to jibe against existing MATLAB convention! Is the `options` input here a keyword now or just made important because it's used within the `arguments` block? Does the old style `'name', value` pairing not work at all with `options` pre 21a or is the `=` syntax just preferred?

Comment: You can use either `name = value` or `'name', value` interchangeably to your own taste ;) There's nothing magic about the name `options` - you can use whatever you like, so long as you use the `struct` syntax in the `arguments` block. (Of course, you can also augment this with type validations and so on).